# How to make chat bubble shape use path?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to make chat bubble shape use path ?

expect :

[image: chat bubble]

[image: chat bubble]

```
class ChatBubbleShapeBorder extends ShapeBorder {
  final double arrowWidth;
  final double arrowHeight;
  final double arrowArc;
  final double radius;

  ChatBubbleShapeBorder({
    this.radius = 12.0,
    this.arrowWidth = 16.0,
    this.arrowHeight = 8.0,
    this.arrowArc = 0.5,
  }) : assert(arrowArc <= 1.0 && arrowArc >= 0.0);

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.only(bottom: arrowHeight);

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) =>
      null ?? Path();

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    rect = Rect.fromPoints(
        rect.topLeft, rect.bottomRight - Offset(0, arrowHeight));
    double x = arrowWidth, y = arrowHeight, r = 1 - arrowArc;
    return Path()
      ..addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, Radius.circular(radius)))
      ..moveTo(rect.topRight.dx - 30, rect.topRight.dy)
      ..relativeLineTo(-x / 2 * r, -y * r)
      ..relativeQuadraticBezierTo(
          -x / 2 * (1 - r), -y * (1 - r), -x * (1 - r), 0)
      ..relativeLineTo(-x / 2 * r, y * r);
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {}

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => this;
}
```

and after tries here is my shot

actual:

[image: chat bubble]

i try move arrow to left and right for chat bubble.

could you help me to move arrow?

update :

i try to change rect point and move position of arrow. look good, But, i get problem with arrow

```
rect =
    Rect.fromPoints(rect.topLeft + Offset(arrowWidth, 0), rect.bottomRight - Offset(arrowWidth, 0));
double x = arrowWidth, y = arrowHeight, r = 1 - arrowArc;
return Path()
  ..addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, Radius.circular(radius)))
  ..moveTo(rect.topRight.dx + arrowWidth, rect.topRight.dy + 30)
  ..relativeLineTo(-x / 2 * r, -y * r)
  ..relativeQuadraticBezierTo(
      -x / 2 * (1 - r), -y * (1 - r), -x * (1 - r), 0)
  ..relativeLineTo(-x / 2 * r, y * r);
```

shot :

[image: chat bubble]

Comment: Hi , did you find a solution? I'm trying to do the same thing. Thanks.

Comment: here : https://gist.github.com/afdaldev/564f640c25e2069df32c862e58cada77 @jennie788